# Mule Studio removes part of outputPattern in file endpoint

Tags: mule-studio

I have created outbound endpoint in xml config:

```
<file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\marcin\Desktop\convertedFiles" outputPattern="#[function:dateStamp:dd-MM-yyyy].csv" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="appendOutput" doc:name="AppendInvoiceLines"/>
```

It works fine, but after changing something in graphical view and save it removes .csv in output pattern

```
<file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\marcin\Desktop\convertedFiles" outputPattern="#[function:dateStamp:dd-MM-yyyy]" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="appendOutput" doc:name="AppendInvoiceLines"/>
```

I have to add manually .csv after each save. How to put this '.csv' part forever.

// I have mule standalone 3.3.1

Comment: Can you paste your mule-config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get Mule studio 3.5, it might work better for you!

Comment: The same problem still exists in Mule Studio 3.5